# Examples of groups with "non-obvious" identity elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S = \left\{ 0,2,4,6,8 \right\}_{10}$ be a set of remainder classes modulo 10. What strikes me here is that $6$ acts as an identity element under the usual multiplication, that is,
$6 \cdot 0 \equiv 0 \mod 10, 6 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \mod 10,$ and so on.

I see that $S$ is the image of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ by way of a group homomorphism that multiplies each class by 6, so really the identity element above is the "usual" 1 in disguise.

Does anyone else have any other nice or interesting examples where an identity element is not the "usual suspect?"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Answer (score 5):

Take a shot at computing the identity of the group $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x&x \\ x&x \end{bmatrix}\middle | x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\right\}$ using normal matrix multiplication. I think that one is kind of weird.

In general you can make whatever element you want into an identity: you just find a bijection sending the identity element of a group to the element you want, and you declare the new group operation to be the one transporting the structure of the group through the bijection.